# Using jQuery from Orchard module page

Tags: jquery, orchardcms

I'm trying to modify the *Orchard.Search* part with the search form and button to look and behave as I want. For this I need to use some jQuery features.

I added this to the header of the *Search.SearchForm.cshtml* file:

```
Script.Require("jQuery");
```

and I can see from the output of the page that jquery is added, at the bottom of the html, just before the ending  tag:

```
<script src="/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.jQuery/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

which looks fine. That's where the jQuery library is and I can download it from that location without probs. I've also added a small test-script in the page just to see if jQuery works properly:

```
<script language="javascript" type ="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () { 
  alert('page loaded');
});

</script>
```

But it's never fired and I get this script-error: Uncaught ReferenceError: *$ is not defined*

I'm getting tired of this, too much hassle but I guess I'm doing it all wrong...

**Edit:** Added the jquery tag and tried the suggestion answer about Script.Foot() which seems to work:

```
@using(Script.Foot()) {
    <script type ="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('page loaded');
        });
    //]]>
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Please, use "jquery" tag for questions relating to jQuery. Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, that script of yours needs to appear after the inclusion of jQuery, otherwise $ is meaningless. You can add your script by surrouding it with @using(Script.Foot) { ...}:

```
@using(Script.Foot()) {
    <script type ="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        alert('page loaded');
    });
    //]]>
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Ofcourse, that's the problem. But the using(Script.Foot) code you suggested crashes with: CS1674: 'method group': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable' which is weird.

Comment: Ah, got it working! The @using(Script.Foot()) was missing the parenthesis :). Super thanks for the help.