# Razor syntax for adding Script into the footer of the layout

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, syntax, razor

I'm trying to remember the Razor syntax in .NET MVC3 to add a block of Javascript codes in a partial view into the footer of the layout. I used it once somewhere which I could not find. I google it but no luck. It goes something like this

```
@Scripts.Add(@Script.Foot){
<script type="text/javascript">alert("hello everyone");</script>
}
```

Please help me with the correct this syntax

Thanks in advance

Tri

Comment: Phil Haack has a quick reference on his site for Razor. http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You're probably trying to write a section:

```
@section Footer {
    <script type="text/javascript">alert("hello everyone");</script>
}
```

Comment: He wants to do this in a partial.

Comment: Then there is no built-in way to do that.  He could write a script container that takes inline helpers.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for
`
    @using(Script.Foot()) {
        <script type ="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            $(document).ready(function () {
                alert('page loaded');
            });
        //]]>
        </script>
    }
`
Thanks to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119044/using-jquery-from-orchard-module-page)

Thanks a lot guys for participating in answering my question

Enjoy your day/night!