# Orchard and editing page - adding script

Tags: orchardcms

I can add a script to a page via the dashboard (by editing the page Content Item as `html`). The script is added to the page and evaluated, but too early - none of scripts are loaded yet (for example, jQuery).

I don't want to add the script to `Layout`, as it makes no sense to add this script for all pages.

Is there any way to add a script to a single page's content via the dashboard, so that it can be evaluated properly?

Or should I create a separate module that contains a special content part (to include proper scripts for the view/shape) and add that part to a custom `ContentType` (that also contains `BodyPart` and others such as `Page` Content Items)?

Or should I separate the whole content in such a way that interactive parts are widgets and should not be edited in `Page` Content Item?

Comment: Did you try Vandelay Industries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the script file to the top of the html content like below:

```
<p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/*path of the file*/">// <![CDATA[

// ]]></script>
</p>
```

Steps to add: Dashboard->Content->open the particular page->Html source editor->In the top add the above script with your script file path.

Comment: Yeah, but like I mentioned - scripts is evaluted to early. Most of scripts are included in foot, so I can use them.

Comment: @pwas Is the footer content placed in the page or seperately provided in the widget?

Comment: @pwas Is my question make sense?

Comment: no, it is not :( Page is rendered in Content zone, but scripts are included in footer (scripts are included by a theme)

Comment: @pwas In the widget  create a new layer with your particular url for the Layer rule and add the new html widget in the footer part in that add your scripts and select the layer as per your needs.

Comment: Yea, I think that is the only and best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the Script.Foot() extension method ?

```
@using(Script.Foot()) {
```

...
    }

[Using jQuery from Orchard module page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119044/using-jquery-from-orchard-module-page)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding a part for your script, something like:

```
public class CustomScriptPart : ContentPart<CustomScriptPartRecord>
{
    public bool AtFoot
    {
        get { return Record.AtFoot; }
        set { Record.AtFoot = value; }
    }
    public string Script
    {
        get { return Record.Script; }
        set { Record.Script = value; }
    }
}
```

Views/Parts/CustomScript.cshtml

```
@if(Model.AtFoot) {
    using(Script.Foot()) {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            @Model.Script
        </script>
    }
} else {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        @Model.Script
    </script>
}
```

But probably something similar is already done, by Vandelay Industries for example.